# Launch AWS instance on upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, distributed-system

I want to host a website on a small AWS instance (e.g. `t2.micro`) that launches a larger instance (e.g. `m5.2xlarge`) whenever a user uploads data to be processed. I also want the larger instance to shut down when the processing is finished. Is there an AWS service or some other workaround that can do this? The larger instance would only be triggered every few days.

Comment: There are many ways you could do this, depending on your setup. Is the t2.micro a master instance and it should shutdown the large one? Or is the large one autonomus and it should shutdown itself when processing finishes?

Comment: You might want to simply initiate a secondary processing workflow from your web server. That workflow could potentially use EC2, ECS, Lambda, Step Functions to process the uploaded file (probably stored in S3).

Comment: How do I tell the smaller instance to start and stop the larger instance? I just need to know where to start—haven’t been able to find anything relevant in Google

Comment: @DanielFreeman You could use AWS CLI for that, in particular [start-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html, or equivalent SDK.

Comment: I replaced the [hpc] tag with [distributed-system] as the question doesn't have much to do with HPC _per se_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to **stop** an instance when it has finished a task is to issue a `shutdown` command to the Operating System. The default behaviour will be to Stop the EC2 instance.

The easiest way to **start** the instance is to call the `StartInstances()` command, either via command-line or via an SDK. The tricky part is telling the instance what data should be processed. Also, consider what should happen if another data file is uploaded while the first file is being processed -- should it shutdown, or should it work on the new file?

I would recommend:

- If the file is uploaded to S3, then use an AWS Lambda function to start the bigger instance (not requiring the smaller instance)
- If the file is uploaded to the smaller instance, then that instance should:

  - **Push a message to an Amazon SQS queue** containing the data to be processed (or copy the file to S3 and then have the message point to the object in S3)
  - Call `StartInstances()` to start the bigger instance
- The bigger instance should then enter a loop where it will:

  - Retrieve a message from the Amazon SQS queue
  - Process the data
- If the SQS queue is empty, then shutdown the instance via the operating system

See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 0):

You can also point the instance to the correct S3 bucket during launch. Just provide a script to the `UserData` argument:

```
# Point to bucket.
parent = 'my-awesome-s3-bucket'
startup_script = '''#!/bin/bash
bucket=<PARENT_NAME>
aws s3 cp s3://$bucket /home/ubuntu --recursive
'''
startup_script = startup_script.replace('<PARENT_NAME>', parent)

# Launch instance.
try:    
    response = ec2.run_instances(
        InstanceType='m4.2xlarge',
        KeyName='aws3',
        SecurityGroups=['launch-wizard-12'],
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        UserData=startup_script
    )
```